# No encuentra el operador <

Tags: c++, codeblocks, contenedores

Estoy aprendiendo a usar los contenedores de c++ que provee stl

Estoy tratando de recuperar un elemento de un contenedor SET pero me dice que no encuentra el operador < en la clase que estoy tratando de almacenar, pero si esta definido y no se porque ocurre el error.

Esto es el código con el cual recupero el elemento del contenedor.

```
void ContenedorAnimes::recuperarAnime(Anime & anime)
{
    set<Anime>::iterator it = this->animes.find(anime);
    if(it != this->animes.end()) {
        anime = *it;
    };
}
```

Este es el operador < en mi .h

```
 bool operator <(const Anime & Anime);
```

y en mi .cpp

```
bool Anime::operator<(const Anime & anime)
{
    if(this->nombre < anime.getNombre()) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

y este es el error que me da el compilador

D:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|386|error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const Anime' and 'const Anime')|

Espero puedan ayudarme

Saludos

Comment: Puede ser que la declaración del .h te esté dando problemas. `bool operator <(...)`. Si te fijas hay un espacio entre `operator` y `<`. Bórralo.

Comment: Por cierto, posiblemente quieras que el operador se pueda usar con un `const Anime`. Para ello debes marcar la función como `const` así: `bool operator<(const Anime & Anime) const;`. Otra cosa: puedes simplificar el operador así: `return this->nombre < anime.nombre;`

Comment: Si no colocas un `const` luego de la función miembro, el compilador asumirá que la función puede modificar el valor de el objeto, y no permitirá que la uses con elementos `const`. La solución es declararlo como `bool operator <(const Anime & Anime) const;`. Nótese que `Anime::getNombre` tendra que ser `const` también para que puedas usarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió tu respuesta, con respecto al const en la funcion, por que me detectaría que puedo modificar el objeto si se lo estoy pasando como const en los parametros?

Comment: El parámetro no lo puedes modificar porque es `const`. Lo que te detecta colo que podrías modificar es el propio objeto (`*this`) ya que **la función** debe estar marcada como `const`. Nota que no estoy hablando del parámetro.

Answer (score -1):

Tu archivo .h esta mal la definicion del operador. Deberia ser de la siguiente manera:

```
 bool operator<(const Anime & Anime);
```

Tu estas poniendo en la definicion del operador, un espacio, cuando no deberia haber ninguno.
Espero que te haya servido.